# Cookie (jQuery) vs localStorage (HTML5) for storing simple flag value - performance benefit?

Tags: cookies, jquery, storage

I appreciate this question has possibly been asked before, but I'm struggling to find a recent and useful answer for my use-case:

Is there a performance/supportability/simplicity benefit in utilizing localStorage over cookies for returning fairly simple "flag" values?

For instance, I'm implementing a user selectable "dark mode" on a site and I don't want the FOUC (aka "white flash") when the user returns or navigates between pages. Cookies are "old tech" now, however is there real benefit into switching out the following "cookie code" (which is currently jQuery based) for localStorage?

```
jQuery(function() {
  if (Cookies.get('darkmode') == '1') {
    jQuery('body').addClass('dark-mode');
    jQuery('.switch input').attr('checked', 'checked');
  } else {
    jQuery('body').removeClass('dark-mode');
    jQuery('.switch input').attr('checked', false);
  }
  jQuery('.switch span').on('click', function() {
    if (Cookies.get('darkmode') == '1') {
      jQuery('body').removeClass('dark-mode');
      Cookies.remove('darkmode', { path: '/' });
    } else {
      jQuery('body').addClass('dark-mode');
      Cookies.set('darkmode', '1', { expires: 365, path: '/' });
    }
  });
});
```

I then have this super simple script straight after my opening `<body>` tag:

```
<script>
if (document.cookie.indexOf("darkmode=1") >= 0) {
    document.body.classList.add("dark-mode");
    console.log("You enabled Dark Mode last time you were here!");
} else {
    document.body.classList.remove("dark-mode");
    console.log("You turned off Dark Mode last time you were here!");    
}
</script>
```

So in summary - is there benefit in this use-case of utilizing localStorage? Cookies currently work fine and I've negated the FOUC, but I'm still just wondering whether there's actual benefit in utilizing localStorage for things such as performance, simplicity etc.? I'm not really fussed when it comes to the whole GDPR argument, as my understanding is both are treated equally.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the GDPR doesn't treat cookies or local storage differently.  See [Is localStorage under The Cookie Law?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/290566/is-localstorage-under-the-cookie-law)

Comment: Apologies @StephenOstermiller - it wasn't so much a "does GDPR treat them differently" question, in fact it wasn't really geared towards GDPR at all. The only reason I mentioned GDPR is I know there's the whole "cookie law" thing.
I'm more concerned around the actual use-case and whether it's better using localStorage or cookies for something such as a simple true/false flag?